# React Router 'NotFoundPage' always show up! How to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a AppRouter.js file which looks like this:

```
  const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

My problem here is I'm seeing the PageNotFound in my landing page, but in the other pages it doesn't show up. How do I solve this?

I want to always show my NavBar and Footer, inside my , and I want to render the different pages.

My PrivateRoute is a component that always sends the user back to login page if the user is not logged in.

Everything works great except that the NotFoundPage is always showing at my Landing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with the `path` prop on `<Route />` components. You could use `path="*"` to catch any other route, and in turn show the `PageNotFound` screen by doing the following:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} /> 
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: I have already tried it, it dont work. Its strange.. But dosent work :/

Comment: all routes that does not exists in the app. Im going to have more, but there is only routes for when your logged inn. Otherwise i want to have PageNotFound when trying to access a page in url that dont exists.

Comment: Im using "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1", this version, it thats has something to say ?

Comment: Did not help :/

Comment: I added 'exact' to all other routes include LandingPage, did not work :/ Or did you mean to put my landing inside <Switch> ?

Comment: Thanx for the help! It works now! Need to modify the css now, everything shrink :P hehe, thanx man!

Comment: Hey you're welcome! Glad I could help - all the best your project :-)